# Separate class to play sounds

Tags: java, android, class, soundpool

What am I doing wrong?

I made a separate class, called "SoundClass" :

```
public class SoundClass extends Activity {
private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundsMap;

public int SoundYeah = 1;
public int SoundZwart = 2;
public int SoundBruin = 3;
public int SoundBlauw = 4;
public int SoundGroen = 5;
public int SoundGeel = 6;
public int SoundOranje = 7;
public int SoundRose = 8;
public int SoundWit = 9;
public int SoundPaars = 10;
public int SoundRood = 11;
public int SoundWrong = 12;


SoundClass(Context myContext){

    soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    soundsMap.put(SoundYeah, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.yeah, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundZwart, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c00, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundBruin, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c01, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundBlauw, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c02, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundGroen, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c03, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundGeel, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c04, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundOranje, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c05, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundRose, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c06, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundWit, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c07, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundPaars, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c08, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundRood, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.c09, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SoundWrong, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.wrong, 1));

}

public void playSound(int sound, float fSpeed) {
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float streamVolumeMax = mgr
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;


    soundPool.play(soundsMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, fSpeed);
}

}
```

I want to call it from my MainActivity class, so I use :

```
        SoundClass mSC = new SoundClass(this);

    mSC.playSound(mSC.SoundBlauw, 1.0f);
```

But it lands an error (NPE on line "soundsMap.put(SoundYeah, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.yeah, 1));"

Can you please clarify what is wrong?

Comment: A variable you're trying to reference on that line is `null`. Most likely it's either `soundsMap` or `soundPool`. Step through your code with a debugger and it should be quite clear.

Comment: can you show the logcat

Comment: Why are you extending `Activity`? This is clearly not an `Activity` so it should not extend the `Activity` class.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how this is done? So : I want to create a seperate class for playing sounds, and envoke the player from within a different class. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with codeMagic. Don't extend activity and use the context you are accepting in the constructor within your soundpool.load statements.

Comment: Ok. It is solved now, not sure why this is on Hold. I would like to post the correct answer (example code)

Answer (score 2):

Many issues:

- Your class should not be an activity but a regular class.
- Activities should not have an explicit constructor.
- You cannot use an activity as a `Context` until `onCreate()`. The `this` pointer you're passing as `Context` to `load()` will cause a NPE in platform `getBaseContext()`.

To fix it:

- Make the class not extend `Activity`.
- Use the `myContext` parameter as `Context` instead of `this`.

Comment: I used your comment and created a seperate class. Although your answer is correct, it doesn't show the entire code. I would like to add it to this question.